solution-verification | Show that $\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y}+ \frac{3x^2+6xz+2z^2}{x+z}+ \frac{3z^2+6zy+2y^ 2}{z+y} \leq \frac{25}{4}(x+y+z)$.
the problem
Let $x,y,z$ be three strictly positive real numbers. Show that
$\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y}+ \frac{3x^2+6xz+2z^2}{x+z}+ \frac{3z^2+6zy+2y^ 2}{z+y} \leq \frac{25}{4}(x+y+z)$.
my solution
First of all I noticed that
$\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y} \leq \frac{3x^2+5xy+2y^2}{x+y}= \frac{(x+y)(3x+2y)}{x+y}= 3x+2y$
by analog we get that
$\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y}+ \frac{3x^2+6xz+2z^2}{x+z}+ \frac{3z^2+6zy+2y^ 2}{z+y} \leq 5(x+y+z) \leq \frac{25}{4}(x+y+z)$ because $5\leq \frac{25}{4}$
Im not sure of my solution because $5\leq \frac{25}{4}$ doesn't really follow the case of the equality we need.
Hope one of you can tell me if my answers right! Thank you1

Well, why do you think we need equality to hold?  $1 \le 2$ is a perfectly valid true statement.

Sinse $x,y>0$ you have $xy>0$ and $\frac{xy}{x+y}>0$. Thus your first inequality where you replace $6xy$ by $5xy$ is incorrect. But you can take this as remainder and have to deal with $5(x+y+z)+\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{xz}{x+z}+\frac{yz}{y+z}$.

Can you explain how you noticed that first observation? In particular, why is $ 3x^2 + 6xy + 2y^2 \leq 3x^2 + 5xy + 2y^2 $? $\quad$ Unless I misunderstood something, I would grade your solution a 0.

@Calvin this is simply wrong. $xy>0$ thus that inequality cannot hold.

@Snake707 That is my point. This is a "solution-verification" tag, where OP is required to "must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt". Since they did not do that, (it is likely that this question will be closed,) hence I'm not posting it as an answer.

I think for such an elementary question, I don't expect the poster to know exactly which part of the proof is in doubt. Maybe they are just confused. I am not sure what you are getting at.

@CalvinLin Sorry for my mistake...now i understand where I made the mistake, I think I just mixed the the comparison signs. Thanks!

I think the problem is is stated incorrectly. In fact a stronger statement holds. Then we also get the equality condition you are after.
You probably made a mistake in the question, I think the inequality you want to proof is:
$$\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y} + \frac{3y^2+6yz+2z^2}{y+z} + \frac{3z^2+6zx+2x^2}{z+x}\leq \frac{11}2 (x+y+z)$$
which is invariant under cyclical transformations. Note that I replaced $\frac{25}4$ with the smaller $\frac{11}2$. The reason is shown below.
Often, the equality gets achieved at $x=y=z$ for these kinds of problems. Lets try it:
$$\frac{11x^2}{2x}\cdot 3 = \frac{11}{2} 3x < \frac{25}4 3x$$
Ok. Not quiet like your problem statement. Let's find out why.
Since $x,y>0$ we have $xy>0$ and thus cannot just ignore the first $\frac{xy}{x+y}$. Let's be better:
$$\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y}=\frac{3x^2+5xy+2y^2}{x+y} + \frac{xy}{x+y} = (3x+2y) + \frac{xy}{x+y}$$
The other three terms are similar (cyclical transformation).
Using the AM-HM inequality we have:
$$0<\frac{2}{\frac 1x +\frac 1y}= 2\frac{xy}{x+y}\leq \frac 12 (x+y)$$
Thus:
$$\frac{xy}{x+y}\leq \frac 14 (x+y)$$
Here equality holds only for $x=y$. Putting it all together we have:
$$\frac{3x^2+6xy+2y^2}{x+y} + \frac{3y^2+6yz+2z^2}{y+z} + \frac{3z^2+6zx+2x^2}{z+x} \leq 5(x+y+z)+\frac 14(2x+2y+2z)=\frac{11}2(x+y+z)$$
Here equality holds only for $x=y=z$ and it would be as previously stated.

FYI Just because the problem has a stronger version, doesn't mean that "the problem is is stated incorrectly".  You could change that to "let's prove a stronger statement".

I think the author also wanted to know, why equality didn't hold.

@Snake707 Thank you so much for you answer! So not always the equality holds and we can say that $1 \leq 2$?

@Ryan As stated in your version, the equality doesn't hold. It is a strict inequality with a separation greater than zero. In my version it is not a strict inequality. Equality is reached if and only if $x=y=z$.
